# Complicated ordering by median in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, median

Example table:

```
age | fruit | number_bought |
20  | apple | 3000000       |
20  | apple | 20            |
20  | apple | 60            |
20  | apple | 30            |
20  | apple | 50            |
20  | apple | 4             |
20  | banana| 40            |
30  | grape | 400           |
30  | grape | 450           |
30  | grape | 500           |
```

Simply a list of how many of a specific fruit a person of a specific age buys while he is that age.

Now, I need to sort this table by "most popular fruits", grouped by age and fruit.

And here's the tricky part, I want to use MEDIAN for calculating popularity, not just the average number. Since some people might be far off the normal (he might be a salesman), like the 3000000 in the example above, while the "average 20 year old" buys alot less, as you can see from the example.

The above table, sorted by median popularity should come out like this:

```
age | fruit | median |
30  | grape | 450    |
20  | apple | 40     |
20  | banana| 40     |
```

Now if I simply had used "average" calculation,  20, apple would have won the popularity, simply because of one salesman. So thats why I want to use median.

Comment: What's the PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Why is the median for age 20 apples 55? Looks like it should be the value of the record with a number_bought between 30 and 50

Comment: My bad, wrong calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common median queries seem to struggle when there are an even number of items (for example, with apple in your test data).

Simple way round that would be :-

```
SELECT y.age, x.fruit, AVG(x.number_bought) AS number_bought
from data x
INNER JOIN data y
ON x.age = y.age
AND x.fruit = y.fruit
GROUP BY y.age, x.fruit, x.number_bought
HAVING SUM(SIGN(1-SIGN(y.number_bought-x.number_bought))) = FLOOR((COUNT(*)+1)/2)
ORDER BY number_bought DESC;
```

This isn't strictly accurate as it is just taking the one before the middle one (ie, the median of the 6  records would be the one in position 3.5 - this just uses FLOOR and gets record number 3).

Possibly slightly more accurate would be this which will get the mean of the 2 records either side when there are an even number

```
SELECT age, fruit, AVG(number_bought) AS number_bought
FROM 
(
    SELECT y.age, x.fruit, AVG(x.number_bought) AS number_bought
    from data x
    INNER JOIN data y
    ON x.age = y.age
    AND x.fruit = y.fruit
    GROUP BY y.age, x.fruit, x.number_bought
    HAVING SUM(SIGN(1-SIGN(y.number_bought-x.number_bought))) = FLOOR((COUNT(*)+1)/2)
    OR SUM(SIGN(1-SIGN(y.number_bought-x.number_bought))) = CEIL((COUNT(*)+1)/2)
) Sub1
GROUP BY age, fruit
ORDER BY number_bought DESC;
```

SQL fiddles here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1b49/13

Comment: how would you do it if you want to have atleast 50 hits on the combo (age+fruit) for it to get counted in the list?

Comment: i want to exclude weird combos, like 60+weird_fruit+10000000. it will top the list. i want to have atleast 50 hits for the combo to be counted.

Comment: Think you could put `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 50` after the outer GROUP BY